# Change Header Buttons Label FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar js to show events. I have changed header buttons to show only list week and list month but both buttons have same label which is 'list'. Is there a way to change those labels to something meaningful?
Here is the configuration I am using:

```
          var options = {
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'listWeek,listMonth'
                },
                defaultView: 'listMonth',
               
               }
```

[This is calendar view right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okyGc.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add following in declaration:

```
var options = {
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'listWeek,listMonth'
            },
            defaultView: 'listMonth',
            buttonText: {
                listWeek: 'Week',
                listMonth: 'Month'
           },
      }
```